# Adding the Checkbox feature for filtering purposes

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I'm building a Shiny app in which I'm trying to implement a checkbox type filter.

In the input called `phones` There is one option titled `Yes`. When `Yes` is ticked off, it will limit it to anyone in `df` whose field for `phone` IS NOT NA. When it's not checked off, it will include all fields under `phone` regardless if its NA or not.

The error I get:

`` Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. ℹ Input `..1` is `&...`. x `input$phones == "Yes" ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone)`, `TRUE ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone) & is.na(temp_data$phone)` must be length 0 or one, not 10000 ``

global.R:

```
library(civis)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')
```

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c("All", unique(df$state))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(df$demo))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Status", choices = c("All", unique(df$status))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18, 
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      sliderInput("score1", label = h3("Select Score1 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      sliderInput("score2", label = h3("Select Score2 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  ))
```

server.R:

```
    server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county[df$state == input$data1])))
    } else {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county)))
    }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$county == input$data2])))
    } else {
      if (input$data1 != "All") {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$state == input$data1])))
      } else {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city)))
      }
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    temp_data <- df
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state == input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city == input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo == input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$status == input$data5, ]
    }
    
    temp_data %>% filter(temp_data$age >= input$age[1] &
                       temp_data$age <= input$age[2] &
                       temp_data$score1 >= input$score1[1] &
                       temp_data$score1 <= input$score1[2] &
                       temp_data$score2 >= input$score2[1] &
                       temp_data$score2 <= input$score2[2] &
                       case_when(input$phones == 'Yes' ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone), 
                                 # For a default value, use TRUE ~
                                 TRUE ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone) & is.na(temp_data$phone)))
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    filtered_data() %>% select(unique_id, first_name, last_name, phone)
  )
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("universe", "_", date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data() %>% select(unique_id, first_name, last_name, phone) %>% distinct_all(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `case_when`, it may be more appropriate to use `if () else ()`.  Also, when your `prettyCheckboxGroup` is unchecked, the value is `NULL`, and you need to handle that.  Try this

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c("All", unique(df$state))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(df$demo))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Status", choices = c("All", unique(df$status))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18, 
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      sliderInput("score1", label = h3("Select Score1 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      sliderInput("score2", label = h3("Select Score2 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  #observe({print(input$phones)})
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county[df$state == input$data1])))
    } else {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county)))
    }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$county == input$data2])))
    } else {
      if (input$data1 != "All") {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$state == input$data1])))
      } else {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city)))
      }
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    temp_data <- df
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state == input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city == input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo == input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$status == input$data5, ]
    }
    
    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(temp_data$age >= input$age[1] &
                           temp_data$age <= input$age[2] &
                           temp_data$score1 >= input$score1[1] &
                           temp_data$score1 <= input$score1[2] &
                           temp_data$score2 >= input$score2[1] &
                           temp_data$score2 <= input$score2[2]) #&
                           # case_when(input$phones == 'Yes' ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone), 
                           #           # For a default value, use TRUE ~
                           #           TRUE ~ !is.na(temp_data$phone) & is.na(temp_data$phone))
                           #) 
    
    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    df3 %>% dplyr::select(unique_id, first_name, last_name, phone)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    filtered_data() 
  )
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("universe", "_", date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data() %>% distinct_all(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perfect. This did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I just posted a new question I would love some help with if you have the time!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176601/generating-ui-server-based-on-initial-selection