# Generating UI/Server based on initial selection

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

Below is the script I've created for a Shiny app I've created. I am trying to create a landing page of sorts (I don't even know if that's the right phrase to use) that allows you to pick between which dataset you're using. You will notice in the beginning of the script, there is `df` and `df2` (They're both the same dataset but that's irrelevant).

What I would like to do is perhaps have an initial "page" come up that gives you the option to select which data set you're working from. Once that's selected, it would then take you to setup you see below, but with one notable exception: If `df2` is selected, it will not include an option to select:

`sliderInput("score2", label = h3("Select Score2 Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))`

But you will be able to choose from all the other inputs.

I'm not even sure where to begin with this, so what would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
    library(dbplyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    library(DT)
    
    df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')
    df2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("mydata", label = "Choose dataframe", choices = c("df","df2"), inline=TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c(unique(df$state))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", multiple = TRUE, choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(df$demo))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Status", choices = c("All", unique(df$status))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18,
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      sliderInput("score1", label = h3("Select Score1 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='df'",
                       sliderInput("score2", label = h3("Select Score2 Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

    server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  mydf <- reactive({get(input$mydata)})
  
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    df <- mydf()
    #if (input$data1 != "All") {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county[df$state == input$data1])))
    # } else {
    #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county)))
    # }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    df <- mydf()
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", multiple = TRUE, server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$county == input$data2])))
    } else {
      #if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", multiple = TRUE, server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$state == input$data1])))
      # } else {
      #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city)))
      # }
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    temp_data <- mydf()
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state == input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city %in% input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo == input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$status == input$data5, ]
    }
    
    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(age >= input$age[1] &
                                         age <= input$age[2] &
                                         score1 >= input$score1[1] &
                                         score1 <= input$score1[2])
    if (input$mydata=="df") df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(score2 >= input$score2[1] & score2 <= input$score2[2])
    
    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    df3 %>% dplyr::select(unique_id, first_name, last_name, phone)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    filtered_data()
  )
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("universe", "_", date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data() %>% distinct_all(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')
df2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/sampleset_df.csv')
df2$unique_id <- df2$unique_id*2  ##  just to check if switching works

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("mydata", label = "Choose dataframe", choices = c("df","df2"), inline=TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c(unique(df$state))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(df$demo))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Status", choices = c("All", unique(df$status))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18,
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      sliderInput("score1", label = h3("Select Score1 Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='df'",
                       sliderInput("score2", label = h3("Select Score2 Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
                       ),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  mydf <- reactive({get(input$mydata)})
  
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    df <- mydf()
    #if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county[df$state == input$data1])))
    # } else {
    #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county)))
    # }
  }, priority = 2)

  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    req(mydf())
    df <- mydf()
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$county == input$data2])))
    } else {
      #if (input$data1 != "All") {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city[df$state == input$data1])))
      # } else {
      #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city)))
      # }
    }
  }, priority = 1)

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$data3)
    temp_data <- mydf()
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state == input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city %in% input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo %in% input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$status %in% input$data5, ]
    }

    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(age >= input$age[1] &
                                       age <= input$age[2] &
                                       score1 >= input$score1[1] &
                                       score1 <= input$score1[2])
    if (input$mydata=="df") df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(score2 >= input$score2[1] & score2 <= input$score2[2])

    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    df3 %>% dplyr::select(unique_id, first_name, last_name, phone)
  })

  output$table <- renderDT(
    filtered_data()
  )

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("universe", "_", date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data() %>% distinct_all(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, though one follow up: How about the removal of the `score2` input when `df2` is selected?

Comment: Thanks! You rock!

Comment: Something I noticed: Say I’m picking from `df` with my `state` set to AZ and my `age` between 18-20 and both `score1` and `score2` set between 20-80. That is accurately reflected in the app as showing 14 records. BUT say I switch from `df` to `df2`, it remains at that number. In reality, that should show 37 rows. It seems that when I switch between DFs, while it successfully removes the option to use `score2` it is still incorporating the 20-80 range into the filter. When in reality it should not be filtering based off `score2` at all when I switch to `df2`. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh and also filtered by only including valid phone numbers to achieve that desired records number. Forgot to include that in my response above because of character limits. Does that make sense? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Good catch. Please see the updated code. Multi-tasking leads to missing some details like that...

Comment: You rock and have been an incredible help. I just have one more question before I close this out. I want to be able to put in the option to select multiple States and Cities at once (I'm also removing the ability to select "All" for States). Which parts do I need to reflect to do that? Would it only be in the `filtered_data` part or does it also need to include the stuff above it?

Comment: It also affects `observeEvent(input$data1, {...})`.  Please accept the answer if your original question has been answered.

Comment: Accepted! But what do you mean? Which parts do I need to change?

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm adding the ability to select Multiple Cities at once, do I just replace the `==` sign with `%in%`?

Comment: Yes, and the option `multiple = TRUE`

Comment: Hmmm weird. You can see my update code above but it keeps telling me: `Warning: Error in updateSelectizeInput: unused argument (multiple = TRUE)
  [No stack trace available]
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  [No stack trace available]`

Comment: Weird. I'm just double checking the updated script I posted above and I thought I covered that. Unless you're referring to something else that I might have missed.

Comment: Please try the updated code.